# JQ create field only if it exists

Tags: json, filter, key, jq

In jq, how do I ensure a k,v is only created if it exists in the object being inspected? For example, let's say I have an object like:

```
{
 "student":{
    "name": "george",
    "age" : "15",
    "quote": "Hello I am George"
    }
 }
```

And I do `cat text.txt | jq '{name: .student.name, quote: .student.quote}'`  to create:

```
  {
   "name": "george",
   "quote": "Hello I am George"
   }
```

However, some of the entries are incomplete, and I don't want to write an empty K,V. Let's say I get:

```
{
 "student":{
    "name": "Shirley"
  }
}
```

With the current jq above this would create:

```
 {
  "name": "Shirley",
  "quote": null,
  }
```

Is there a way I can tell jq to only create the `'quote'` key if it exists (i.e. is not null)? Or more generally, create ALL keys only if they exist in the object being inspected.

Comment: Can you also update the actual filter used?

Comment: added the filter. cheers.

Comment: How are things being created???

Comment: A couple notes. Firstly, jq will not produce `" "` if the key doesn't exist, but `null`. Also, `null` is not the same as the key not existing. A key could also exist and have the *value* `null`.

Answer (score 9):

This is where object addition comes in very handy, especially since `$obj + null` yields `$obj` (if `$obj` is a JSON object):

```
.student |  {name} + if has("quote") then {quote} else null end
```

or equivalently:

```
def maybe(k): if has(k) then {(k): .[k]} else null end;
.student |  {name} + maybe("quote")
```

A slightly different approach, with subtly different semantics, would be:

```
.student |  {name} + ((select(.quote) | {quote}) // null)
```

Of course other variations are possible.

Comment: Hi there - alternatively is there a way to use the `del` function on a new object. Let's say I have a mapping for fields which or may not be null and then pass to the `del` function to delete the null values of the new? Is that possible?

Comment: I think the answer is "yes" but you'll have to be a bit more specific if you want a more specific answer. Maybe it would be best to ask a new SO q?

Answer (score 2):

If you know what the keys are ahead of time and they're straight properties, just build up an array of the keys you want and check if the object contains those keys.

```
$ jq --argjson keys '["name","quote"]' '
def copy_keys($keys): . as $o
    | reduce $keys[] as $k ({}; if ($o|has($k)) then .[$k] = $o[$k] else . end)
    ;
.student | copy_keys($keys)' text.txt
```

But the way you worded your question, *"Or more generally, create ALL fields only if they exist in the object being inspected,"* you just want all the keys in the object as long as it has a key. Why not just get the object?

```
$ jq '.student' text.txt
```