# have jq detect errors in influxdb json output

Tags: json, jq, influxdb

I have a `jq` filter that converts (`influxdb`) json input to csv for further parsing. However, this filter fails when `influxdb` returns an error. I'm trying to improve my jq filter to detect this, however I can't get this to work. I need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41829748 but can't seem to get this to work. Any ideas?

**Example data**

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"energyv3","columns":["time","value"],"values":[["2015-07-30T23:59:00Z",56980800],["2015-07-31T23:59:00Z",95108400]]}]}]}
{"error":"error parsing query: found EOF, expected integer at line 1, char 34"}
```

**Desired outcome**

```
"\"time\",\"value\""
"\"2015-07-30T23:59:00Z\",56980800"
"\"2015-07-31T23:59:00Z\",95108400"
"error parsing query: found EOF, expected integer at line 1, char 34"
```

i.e.

1. For input with `.results` key: data formatted as csv (works OK)
2. For input with `.error` key: only error string (doesn't work)

**Current filter used**

```
select(.results) | (.results[0].series[0].columns), (.results[0].series[0].values[]) | @csv
```

*Attempt to combine filters*

```
((select(.error) | {error}) // null) + select(.results) | (.results[0].series[0].columns), (.results[0].series[0].values[]) | @csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your attempts, and the assumption that each object contain either `results` or `error`, this should do it:

```
( .results[0].series | .[0].columns, .[]?.values[] ) // [ .error ] | @csv
```

<sup>[REPL demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OQwpxvJ_lo)</sup>